# iOS constraints make width of button more bigger then content text

Tags: ios, autolayout

I create all my constraints programmatically for my UI controls. So my button has a text: **title**

So if I don't set any restriction for width of the button, the app will create for me button based on text width, and this works fro me.

But I want to add few extra padding at left and right sides. How can I do it?

Comment: Check out `titleEdgeInsets` and/or `contentEdgeInsets` (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW31)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `contentEdgeInsets` property of `UIButton`, e.g.:

```
`yourButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 10.f, 0.f, 10.f);`
```

will add 10 points to the left and right edges.